# Removing "\N" values in a data frame

Tags: r, string

I have a data frame where one column is a character type. Some values are having "\N" written in that column and I want to remove the rows containing those values from the data frame. I could not figure it  out 
The current code what I am using is :
    airports_m<-airports_m[airports_m$IATA != "\N",] 
This gives the error

```
Error: '\N' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\N"
```

Please help

Comment: Do you need `subset(airports_m, !grepl('\\N', IATA))` ?

Comment: Yeah Thanks @RonakShah It is working fine

Comment: Hey Ronak this code works fine but the problem is it also deletes other rows where "N" is there which are required in the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use `grepl` here since this is a pattern match and not an exact match.

```
subset(airports_m, !grepl('\\N', IATA))
```

This is same as using :

```
airports_m[-grep('\\N', airports_m$IATA), ]
```

Or

```
airports_m[grep('\\N', airports_m$IATA, invert = TRUE), ]
```

Comment: It works fine. However, it deletes the rows where "N" is there/ Imagine "SIN" is written in another row and this code deletes that row too.

Comment: Use `subset(airports_m, !grepl('\\N', IATA, fixed = TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ronak. Another thing I need to ask. Can we change the font size or color of row values (contains strings only) of a particular column in a data frame in  R?

Comment: Not in a dataframe. There are ways to do it in `kable` or `markdown` I think.

Answer (score 1):

Backslashes are 'escape' characters in R strings.  For instance, linefeeds are "\n" and tabs are "\t".  So to have a literal backslash you have to escape the escape character.  To indicate the two-character string \N use the string `"\\N"`.  So to your code,

```
library(tidyverse)
airports_m %>%
  filter(IATA != "\\N")
```

Or just in case there's some other trash on the line

```
airports_m %>%
  filter(! str_detect(IATA , "\\N"))
```